# Best opportunity to ask for a higher salary

Tags: salary

So this whole year I had 1 year limited contract in a huge IT company. I really like the job and almost everything about, and I know that by the end of the year I'll have a talk with my boss regarding if he will extend my contract or not.

I was quite positive that he will extend my contract and was thinking to use this meeting to ask for a little bit bigger salary (note: I am aware that my current salary is on the lowest end for my position).

However, to my surprise I got an automatic letter from HR that my boss asked to extend my contract without even talking to me about it. Obviously I am really happy with contract extension, but now I lost the opportunity to ask for a bigger salary. The HR letter even states "Salary changes: no".

Do you think I should leave it as it is or should I request a meeting now and talk about salary increase? Are there any risks associated with asking now?

P.s. This is a very big company so it's very possible he just didn't have much time and requested my contract extension without even thinking much about it.

Comment: No change at all - not even an inflation / cost-of-living increase? I think it has to be now - if you don't ask now, when would you ask?

Comment: Just in general, best time to ask for a raise is: Sooner rather than later, when your boss is in a good mood, when something awesome/useful you've done is fresh in their mind, when they've expressed (through words or actions) that they want to keep you around.

Comment: If it's a contract extension you have to agree before it's extended. You don't have to agree and you're free to negotiate the terms of your contract...

Comment: @Ben, yes, but there is some risk, don't you think? What if he decides that it's arrogant from my point of view to ask for more? My company already have a lot of benefits and in general is considered a great workplace. At least now I am 100% sure i'll get the contract.

Comment: Are you an independent contractor or are you contracted as an employee of another company?

Comment: @cdkMoose I have a 1 year contract with my company, and now they offered me an indefinite contract.

Comment: Then your company should negotiate for you, since they are setting the rates.

Comment: @cdkMoose probably you misunderstood me.. There is a company X i work for. At first it was 1 year contract, now it will be indefinite, what they should negotiate for me..?

Comment: So you have a direct independent contract with the company you work for?    Then I wouldn't let them extend it indefinitely without specific salary increase language, otherwise you could be stuck at that rate forever.

Comment: Are you sure that your boss ask HR to write that kind contract? It could be automate letter from HR. Do you know your boss personality? It kind of strange how afraid you're to ask for a raise.

Answer (score 2):

An extension has to be agreed to. This is the time for negotiation if you are unhappy with your pay. You run the risk of being rejected, but if you don't ask you won't get anything.

I would contact your boss with a clear amount in mind, not just ask for a raise in general. This turns it into a yes/no scenario rather than a headache for him/her. So do the research into what you're worth and why you're worth that much, and if you think it's worth the effort inform the boss and/or HR depending on the company protocols in these matters.

Answer (score 0):

At my (big) IT company we don't automatically raise rates for contract staff, only permanent staff get an automatic salary review each year, but we do have a quarterly review meeting with the contract staff and that can include discussion on pay rates. Usually we will come to an agreement.

I'd ask for a discussion with your manager, and use it for a positive discussion about how much you enjoy your role and talk how your skills and experience gained over the previous year would justify a higher salary. I'd avoid explicitly talking about what you could earn elsewhere as it will tend to polarize the discussion and that should really be a last resort, but an understanding of market rates and other options available to you is always useful in this sort of discussion.

Don't talk about what you could earn elsewhere, but it is useful to know as background. E.g. if you're it is a flat market and/or you're already well paid compared to market rates then there's no sense in pushing hard .

Answer (score 0):

The best time to ask for a raise is always when you have a higher offer in hand. So in particular, if you want a raise, the number one thing you should be doing is interviewing elsewhere.